# When I press cancel edit, a popup is shown at the top right that my changes have been sent to queue

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, documentation

This is not what it should be I think. At best, this box should not be shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you edit a proposed change, it is removed from review to allow you the opportunity to make whatever additional edits you want. When you hit cancel at that point, it's re-submitted. I think the message as is serves its main purpose - explaining that the draft wasn't discarded altogether, but rather resubmitted.

Comment: Didn't even remember I had this question open. Thanks for the (late, but hey, now its there) answer!